# Convert text file of dictionaries to csv Python

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

I have a text file composed by different dictionaries and it looks like this:

```
{"destination.fqdn": "194-65-57-128.ctt.pt", "feed.provider": "MyFeed", "source.abuse_contact": "coisas@foo.com", "raw": "bWFsd2FyZSwyMTAuMjguNTYuMSxodHRwOi8vd3d3LmN0dC5wdCAsMTk0LTY1LTU3LTEyOC5jdHQucHQsY29pc2FzQGZvby5jb20sMTk0LjIzOS4xNjcuNSx3d3cudmVyeWJhZC5jb20gLHZlcnkudmVyeWJhZC5jb20sLCwsMjAxMC0wMi0xOFQwMDowMDowMCswMDowMA0K", "feed.name": "FileCollector", "destination.geolocation.latitude": 32.2109, "destination.geolocation.cc": "CN", "source.geolocation.longitude": 12.069, "event_description.text": "ctt", "source.ip": "194.239.167.5", "source.geolocation.city": "Frederikssund", "destination.geolocation.city": "Zhenjiang", "destination.url": "http://www.ctt.pt", "classification.taxonomy": "malicious code", "source.url": "http://www.verybad.com", "source.fqdn": "very.verybad.com", "feed.url": "file://localhost/opt/intelmq/teste_ip_url_fqdn.csv", "feed.accuracy": 100.0, "time.observation": "2017-07-18T13:15:48+00:00", "destination.geolocation.longitude": 119.4551, "source.geolocation.latitude": 55.8396, "classification.type": "malware", "destination.ip": "210.28.56.1", "time.source": "2010-02-18T00:00:00+00:00", "source.geolocation.cc": "DK"}
{"destination.url": "http://www2.ctt.pt", "classification.taxonomy": "malicious code", "source.url": "http://www.telecom.pt", "feed.provider": "MyFeed", "time.observation": "2017-07-18T13:15:48+00:00", "destination.fqdn": "ctt-pt.mail.protection.outlook.com", "source.abuse_contact": "coisas7@foo.com", "source.geolocation.cc": "TN", "feed.url": "file://localhost/opt/intelmq/teste_ip_url_fqdn.csv", "raw": "YyZjLDI1MS4xNTQuNjUuOSxodHRwOi8vd3d3Mi5jdHQucHQsY3R0LXB0Lm1haWwucHJvdGVjdGlvbi5vdXRsb29rLmNvbSxjb2lzYXM3QGZvby5jb20sMTk3LjEzLjEwNS44LHd3dy50ZWxlY29tLnB0LCwsLCwyMDEwLTAyLTE4VDAwOjAwOjAwKzAwOjAwDQo=", "feed.name": "FileCollector", "classification.type": "c&c", "source.geolocation.latitude": 34.0, "source.geolocation.longitude": 9.0, "destination.ip": "251.154.65.9", "event_description.text": "ctt", "source.ip": "197.13.105.8", "time.source": "2010-02-18T00:00:00+00:00", "feed.accuracy": 100.0}
```

Each line is a dictionary and some dictionaries have more keys than others, and I would like to convert the text file to a csv file.

I have the following code:

```
import json
import csv
import ast

def json_to_csv(txt_file, csv_file):

    lista = []
    with open(txt_file, 'rb') as fin:
        lines = fin.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            dict_line = ast.literal_eval(line)
            lista.append(line)
    list_json = json.dumps(lista)

    read_json = json.loads(list_json)

    header =["feed.accuracy","feed.url","source.geolocation.longitude","event_description.text","raw","destination.geolocation.city","source.ip","classification.taxonomy",
                "time.observation","destination.geolocation.latitude","destination.ip","source.asn","feed.name","source.geolocation.latitude","time.source","feed.provider",
                "destination.geolocation.longitude","destination.geolocation.cc","destination.asn","source.abuse_contact","source.geolocation.cc","classification.type"]
    with open(csv_file, 'wb+') as f:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, header)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(read_json)
```

First I read the text file, then I convert its content into JSON and then I try to write the converted data into the csv file, however its returning the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    json_to_csv('ctt.txt','ctt.csv')
  File "C:/Users/Marisa/Documents/json_to_csv.py", line 26, in json_to_csv
    dict_writer.writerows(read_json)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 157, in writerows
    rows.append(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: u'{', u'"', u'f', u'e', u'e', u'd', u'.', u'a', u'c', u'c', u'u', u'r', u'a', u'c', u'y', u'"', u':', u' ', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'.', u'0', u',', u' ', u'"', u'c', u'l', u'a', u's', u's', u'i', u'f', u'i', u'c', u'a', u't', u'i', u'o', u'n', u'.', u't', u'a', u'x',...
```

Comment: What do you think the `csv` file should look like when you are done?

Comment: Why do you dump the list to a JSON string and then immediately read it back? Isn’t that a no-op? Also, depending on where the input file comes from, it might be better to read each line of the file using the JSON library instead of (not after) the AST one.

Comment: if you load it into pandas and then export that pandas frame to csv you wont have to manually fix anything, but you will end up with a sparse matrix type csv

Comment: Your header has 22 rows only, while the first line has 25 columns, although this isn't causing the error, you should keep this in mind while creating the csv.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh
Something like:
`feed.accuracy,feed.url,source.geolocation.longitude
100.00,http://www.test.com, 27.4833
`

Comment: @Yankee I know and I think that's the problem, because every dictionary has more or less keys than the others, but they all have some keys in common

Comment: @mf370 So you want to create a single CSV for all the data, or multiple CSVs , each for every single line ?

Comment: @Yankee I would like to create a single CSV with all the data, even if some lines have empty spaces because the dictionary that corresponds to that line, doesn't have that specific key-value pair

Comment: Ok, so here is what you should do. Create a list of headers(as you already have), but you'll need to know all the headers beforehand. 
Then, use readline to iterate over each line in the dict-file, and for every line, iterate over your header list, and check if that column exists in the line(dict), if yes, put the value, else, put None. This will give you a list for every line, put that list to a csv.

Comment: Thank you!! @Yankee

Comment: @mf370 If it works for you, please let me know so that I can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it a little more complicated than it needs to be, and you're missing some of the fields in your own example data above. We can get rid of the `ast` dependency and the back & forth JSON processing, add in the missing fields, and the following will work with the sample data you've provided:

```
import json
import csv

def json_to_csv(txt_file, csv_file):

    lista = []
    with open(txt_file, 'r') as in_file:
        lines = in_file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            try:
                dict_line = json.loads(line)
                lista.append(dict_line)
            except Exception as err:
                print(err)

    header = [
        "feed.accuracy", "feed.url", "source.geolocation.longitude",
        "event_description.text", "raw", "destination.geolocation.city",
        "source.ip", "classification.taxonomy", "time.observation",
        "destination.geolocation.latitude", "destination.ip", "source.asn",
        "feed.name", "source.geolocation.latitude", "time.source",
        "feed.provider", "destination.geolocation.longitude",
        "destination.geolocation.cc", "destination.asn",
        "source.abuse_contact", "source.geolocation.cc", "classification.type",
        'destination.fqdn', 'source.fqdn', 'source.geolocation.city',
        'source.url', 'destination.url'
    ]
    with open(csv_file, 'w+') as out_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, header)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(lista)
```

Note that if your real data has more fields that aren't included in your sample, you'll need to add those, too.

Note too that if your input data were a proper JSON array like:

```
[{"destination.fqdn": "194-65-57-128.ctt.pt", "feed.provider": "MyFeed", "source.abuse_contact": "coisas@foo.com", "raw": "bWFsd2FyZSwyMTAuMjguNTYuMSxodHRwOi8vd3d3LmN0dC5wdCAsMTk0LTY1LTU3LTEyOC5jdHQucHQsY29pc2FzQGZvby5jb20sMTk0LjIzOS4xNjcuNSx3d3cudmVyeWJhZC5jb20gLHZlcnkudmVyeWJhZC5jb20sLCwsMjAxMC0wMi0xOFQwMDowMDowMCswMDowMA0K", "feed.name": "FileCollector", "destination.geolocation.latitude": 32.2109, "destination.geolocation.cc": "CN", "source.geolocation.longitude": 12.069, "event_description.text": "ctt", "source.ip": "194.239.167.5", "source.geolocation.city": "Frederikssund", "destination.geolocation.city": "Zhenjiang", "destination.url": "http://www.ctt.pt", "classification.taxonomy": "malicious code", "source.url": "http://www.verybad.com", "source.fqdn": "very.verybad.com", "feed.url": "file://localhost/opt/intelmq/teste_ip_url_fqdn.csv", "feed.accuracy": 100.0, "time.observation": "2017-07-18T13:15:48+00:00", "destination.geolocation.longitude": 119.4551, "source.geolocation.latitude": 55.8396, "classification.type": "malware", "destination.ip": "210.28.56.1", "time.source": "2010-02-18T00:00:00+00:00", "source.geolocation.cc": "DK"},
{"destination.url": "http://www2.ctt.pt", "classification.taxonomy": "malicious code", "source.url": "http://www.telecom.pt", "feed.provider": "MyFeed", "time.observation": "2017-07-18T13:15:48+00:00", "destination.fqdn": "ctt-pt.mail.protection.outlook.com", "source.abuse_contact": "coisas7@foo.com", "source.geolocation.cc": "TN", "feed.url": "file://localhost/opt/intelmq/teste_ip_url_fqdn.csv", "raw": "YyZjLDI1MS4xNTQuNjUuOSxodHRwOi8vd3d3Mi5jdHQucHQsY3R0LXB0Lm1haWwucHJvdGVjdGlvbi5vdXRsb29rLmNvbSxjb2lzYXM3QGZvby5jb20sMTk3LjEzLjEwNS44LHd3dy50ZWxlY29tLnB0LCwsLCwyMDEwLTAyLTE4VDAwOjAwOjAwKzAwOjAwDQo=", "feed.name": "FileCollector", "classification.type": "c&c", "source.geolocation.latitude": 34.0, "source.geolocation.longitude": 9.0, "destination.ip": "251.154.65.9", "event_description.text": "ctt", "source.ip": "197.13.105.8", "time.source": "2010-02-18T00:00:00+00:00", "feed.accuracy": 100.0}]
```

the solution simplifies quite a bit more with the whole initial `with open` block becoming just:

```
with open(txt_file, 'r') as in_file:
    lista = json.load(in_file)
```

Comment: Thank you @Feneric! Yes, if the text file was a proper JSON array, I wouldn't have so much problems. 
I tried your code, but it's giving me the following error:
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 12`
Do you know what might causing this?

Comment: Probably your full data set has non-ASCII characters in it. You'll need to either determine the proper character set of your data and set it appropriately or (if there are just a few non-ASCII characters) hunt down the ones causing trouble and remove them.

I added the proper JSON array comment because it's a pretty straightforward edit to place a comma at the end of every line, replace the final one with a close basket, and insert an open bracket at the beginning. Sometimes it's easiest just massaging the data a bit.